# ¿Como evito que se liste el directorio de archivos en un hosting?

Tags: hosting

he contratado un hosting y primera vez que veo que se me listan los archivos que tengo en el host ingresando por el navegador (por donde cualquier usuario puede acceder)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido Carlos, dejando de lado el "chascarrillo" del pie de página... 
habitualmente, cuando entras a un directorio el servidor busca automáticamente un archivo index.php (salvo que hayas cambiado la configuración), lo que deberías hacer el agregar un archivo index y darle la vista que requieras con el mensaje que veas conveniente en caso de que no tengan acceso a esa dirección...

Pero si lo quieres hacer por configuración te recomiento que a tu archivo *.htaccess* agregues la siguiente línea:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Ahora si lo quieres activar(por si las dudas):

```
Options +Indexes
```

Espero te sirva...

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias técnicas que puedes utilizar.

1. Crea un archivo `index.php`<sup>1</sup> en cada carpeta que no quieras listar. Esta es mi opción preferida, pues puedes, por ejemplo, hacer una redirección a la raíz del sitio, o a otra carpeta, por ejemplo:

   ```
   header('Location: https://miweb.com/');
   die();
   ```
2. Crea un archivo `index.html`<sup>1</sup> en cada carpeta que no quieras listar. Este archivo puede estar vacío o contener algún anuncio sobre que no se tiene acceso.
3. Si el web server es apache, crea un archivo `.htaccess` en las carpetas que no quieras listar, con esta directiva, que deshabilita el listado del contenido de la misma.

   ```
   Options -Indexes
   ```

---

<sup>1</sup>: Estoy asumiendo que el web server estará configurado para buscar por *default* `index.php` e `index.html`, que es una convención habitual, pero podría estar configurado diferente, en cuyo caso debes seguir las especificaciones del proveedor de hosting.

Comment: ah vale, gracias. pense que el proveedor del servicio de hosting era el que se encargaba de esos aspectos.

Comment: El proveedor de `hosting` generalmente te ofrece un _Web server_ listo para usar, pero es uno quién decide como utilizarlo. Por otro lado, si la respuesta te es de utilidad, te invito a leer [que hacer cuando alguien te responde](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)